Error: "export * from './types';" on react native when @react-navigation/native package is installed
I have a react-native project and this error appeared when I installed @react-navigation/native package.
ERROR  [Error: undefined Unable to resolve module ./types from C:\Users\Admin\Documents\Projects\KbOutfit\node_modules@react-navigation\core\src\index.tsx:
None of these files exist:

node_modules@react-navigation\core\src\types(.android.js|.native.js|.js|.android.jsx|.native.jsx|.jsx|.android.json|.native.json|.json|.android.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.android.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx)
node_modules@react-navigation\core\src\types\index(.android.js|.nativeiiive.js|.js|.android.jsx|.native.jsx|.jsx|.android.json|.native.json|.json|.android.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.android.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx)

  14 | export { default as PreventRemoveContext } from './PreventRemoveContext';
  15 | export { default as PreventRemoveProvider } from './PreventRemoveProvider';
> 16 | export * from './types';
     |                ^
  17 | export { default as useFocusEffect } from './useFocusEffect';
  18 | export { default as useIsFocused } from './useIsFocused';
  19 | export { default as useNavigation } from './useNavigation';]

I tried:-

Clearing Metro Bundler Cache
npx react-native start --reset-cache
Installing the latest version of react-navigation package.
npm install @react-navigation/native@latest

But it didn't solve the problem.
